# Stacktrace points to a line that doesn't exist in the source code

Tags: java, eclipse, exception, eclipse-plugin, stack-trace

I am editing a very old piece of code off a plugin project. It is throwing an *ClassCastException* which is as follows:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.eclipse.wst.html.ui.StructuredTextViewerConfigurationHTML cannot be cast to puakma.vortex.editors.pma.parser2.PmaStructuredTextViewerConfiguration
at puakma.vortex.editors.pma.PmaStructuredTextViewer.configure(PmaStructuredTextViewer.java:20)
at org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.AbstractTextEditor.createPartControl(AbstractTextEditor.java:3419)
at org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.StatusTextEditor.createPartControl(StatusTextEditor.java:54)
```

I have shuffled the contents of *PmaStructuredTextViewer* for testing purposes and the same error is thrown again and again. I have cleaned and built the project every time. I have even cleared the output folder **/bin** and cleaned the project. However, the same error is thrown. I have searched the whole system for any compiled class file of the same name but there seems to be none. I suspect eclipse is referencing to the class file that is in a folder oither than **/bin** which is the default output folder. What am I doing wrong?

I have cleared bin folder and without rebuilding the project, ran it. The project runs fine. How am I supposed to make sure that eclipse loads the correct class files in the bin folder.

```
public void configure(SourceViewerConfiguration configuration)
{
    ((PmaStructuredTextViewerConfiguration) configuration).setupReconciler(this);

    super.configure(configuration);
}
```

I even customised the code to the following. Somehow the same exception is thrown. This makes me believe that the newly compiled class file is not being used by eclipse during runtime. Instead, it uses the old class file.

```
public class PmaStructuredTextViewer extends StructuredTextViewer
{
    public PmaStructuredTextViewer(Composite parent, IVerticalRuler verticalRuler, IOverviewRuler overviewRuler, boolean showAnnotationsOverview, int styles)
    {
        super(parent, verticalRuler, overviewRuler, showAnnotationsOverview, styles);
    }

    public void configure(SourceViewerConfiguration configuration)
    {
        if(configuration instanceof PmaStructuredTextViewerConfiguration)
        {
            ((PmaStructuredTextViewerConfiguration) configuration).setupReconciler(this);

            super.configure(configuration);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Post the code of `configure` method.

Comment: Shuffling the code, or rebuilding the project will not get rid of errors, it can only change the line # from where the exception is throw. What is the signature of `PmaStructuredTextViewerConfiguration` class?

Comment: @Mubin 
public class PmaStructuredTextViewerConfiguration extends StructuredTextViewerConfigurationHTML{}

Also, check the update.

Comment: You mean you are getting CCE even after enclosing the problematic code in `instanceof PmaStructuredTextViewerConfiguration` condition?
If possible, post the complete code of `PmaStructuredTextViewer`

Comment: @Mubin Yes. And I have just updated the question with the class code.

Comment: The stacktrace that you have posted doesn't match with the source code. The line number of exception in stacktrace is 20, whereas I don't see more than 15 lines in the class. Are you (or I) missing something?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33736/discussion-between-nick-s-and-mubin)